# How can I display a 16bit .TIR image in browser?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, tiff, geotiff

I'm creating a browser-based Thermal Image Analysis tool (similar to [FLIR Tools](https://www.flir.com/products/flir-tools/)).

As input, I have a 16bit TIF file with a .TIR extension.

Using geotiff.js, I'm able to open the TIF file and view it as such:

[TIF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xo2gU.png)

I can't seem to find a javascript library/package that will display this type of image clearly (they're all either very dark or very light and blurry). I'm assuming this is due to the fact that it is a Thermal Image (.TIR) -- any suggestions on how to clearly display these TIR images?